# Application scope in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Default scope for a bean in spring is singleton. However when I have next service defined:

```
@Service("usersLoggedInService")
public class UsersLoggedInServiceImpl implements UsersLoggedInService {

private Map<Long, String> OnlineUsers = new LinkedHashMap<Long, String>();

@Override
public Map<Long, String> getOnlineUsers() {
    return OnlineUsers;
}

@Override
public void setOnlineUsers(Long id, String username) {
    OnlineUsers.put(id, username);
}

    @Override
public void removeLoggedOutUser(Long id){
    if(!OnlineUsers.isEmpty() && OnlineUsers.size()>0)
        OnlineUsers.remove(id);
}
}
```

and using it for login auditing so  whenever new user logged in I am adding it to OnlineUsers LinkedHashMap in next way:

```
usersLoggedInService.setOnlineUsers(user.getId(), user.getUsername());
```

in one of my service classes. This works fine and I can see the users added in map.

But, when on log out I want to remove the user added in LinkedhashMap and when I check usersLoggedInService.getOnlineUsers() I could see that its empty. I don't understand why.

Logout handler definition:

```
<logout invalidate-session="true" 
        logout-url="/logout.htm"
        success-handler-ref="myLogoutHandler"/>
```

And its implementation:

```
 @Component
 public class MyLogoutHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {

@Resource(name = "usersLoggedInService")
UsersLoggedInService usersLoggedInService; 

@Override
public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (authentication != null) {
        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
            if(principal instanceof User){
                User user = (User) principal;
                usersLoggedInService.removeLoggedOutUser(user.getId());     

            }


    }
    setDefaultTargetUrl("/login");
    super.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, authentication);
}

}
```

Please let me know where the problem is. I don't expect this map to be empty.

-----Updated ------

When new users logged in then I can see all the users already added in LinkedHashmap. This  method is inside one of the user service class:

```
  @Service("userService")
  public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

  @Autowired
  UsersLoggedInService usersLoggedInService; 

   @Override
public User getUserDetail() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication();   
    Object principal = auth.getPrincipal();
      if(principal instanceof User){
            User user = (User) principal;
            usersLoggedInService.setOnlineUsers(user.getId(), user.getUsername());

            return user;
        }
        return null;
}
```

}

when users logged in suppose two users logged in I get Map as {1=user1, 9=user2} but if any of the users logged out  then inside onLogoutSuccess() method I get map value as {}. Now if one more user logged in  then I get map {1=user1, 9=user2, 3=user3}. So,Map is getting empty inside onLogoutSuccess() method only and it showing populated values everywhere else.

Answer (score 4):

From what you've described it looks like that new instance of service is created for handler.

It might be that default scope of your configuration is not singleton(it's should be easy to check).

Also, could you please try to use `@Autowired` annotation? There is subtle difference between `@Autowire` and `@Resource` from documentation it looks like it shouldn't cause such issue but worth to try anyway:

```
@Component
public class MyLogoutHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UsersLoggedInsService usersLoggedInService;

    // ...
}
```

-----Update #1 ------

Yeap, try `@Autowired` with `@Qualifier`(when I tried that example without qualifier spring created two instances):

```
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("usersLoggedInService")
  UsersLoggedInService usersLoggedInService;
```

----Update #2 ------

Well, I simply copied all your code in sample project and `it works on my machine`.

Is it possible for you to share your codebase on service like [GitHub](https://github.com/)?

Comment: Hi Petro, Its still the same I changed to @Autowired but still the LinkedHashmap is empty when I log out. I didn't specify my scope anywhere

Comment: I think I know where the problem is. Could you please post code where you are autowiring usersLoggedInService in class responsible for adding logged in user

Comment: I've updated answer with possible solution. If it won't work for you I'll post another way in spring to do login/logout intercepting.

Comment: Hi Petro, no it still showing empty Map inside onLogoutSucess Method.

Answer (score 1):

Please show the class that is calling `setOnlineUsers`. And how and at what place did you check that map is not empty?

Try putting a logger in method `onLogoutSuccess` and check if you are getting a new or same instance of `UsersLoggedInService`.

And I am assuming you have a typo in the bean that you are wiring UsersLoggedIn**s**Service. There is an extra 's'

Comment: Hi Parvez, I have updated my question and added the method where map is not empty.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code. In order to pin point the problem can you check in method onLogoutSuccess if you are getting a new or same instance of UsersLoggedInService? You may just print the hashCode() of the bean to verify this.

Comment: At the moment the only reason I can see is that MyLogoutHandler is getting a separate instance of UsersLoggedInService. And one possible reason for this behaviour is MyLogoutHandler is loaded by different class loader causing a separate instance of UsersLoggedInService to be loaded. That is why I would like to verify if there is a same instance of UsersLoggedInService at both place.